# How to send mass mail in Django and get status for every message?

Tags: django, email, massmail

I'm creating a web app for handling various surveys. An admin can create his own survey and ask users to fill it up. Users are defined by target groups assigned to the survey (so only user in survey's target group can fill the survey).

One of methods to define a target group is a "Token target group". An admin can decide to generate e.g. 25 tokens. After that, the survey can be accessed by anyone who uses a special link (containing the token of course).

So now to the main question:
Every token might have an e-mail address associated with itself. How can I safely send e-mails containing the access link for the survey? I might need to send a few thousand e-mails (max. 10 000 I believe). This is an extreme example and such huge mailings would be needed only occasionally.
But I also would like to be able to keep track of the e-mail message status (was it send or was there any error?). I would also like to make sure that the SMTP server doesn't block this mailing. It would also be nice if the application remained responsive :) (The task should run in background).

What is the best way to handle that problem?

As far as I'm concerned, the standard Django mailing feature won't be much help here. People report that setting up a connection and looping through messages calling send() on them takes forever. It wouldn't run "in background", so I believe that this could have negative impact on the application responsiveness, right?

I read about [django-mailer](https://github.com/jtauber/django-mailer/), but as far as I understood the docs - it doesn't allow to keep track of the message status. Or does it?

What are my other options?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the rest, but regardless for backgrounding the task (no matter how you eventually do it) you'll want to look for [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)

Comment: If I decide to write my own app to handle this problem, Celery will definitely be very useful. Thanks! It's not the answer for the whole problem, but nevertheless +1 for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to reuse connection and to not open it again for each email. [Here is a documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-multiple-emails) on the subject.